# SVN hangs even though files are committed

Tags: svn

So it makes no difference which project i'm working on which makes me think it's something about my SVN install but every single time i commit anything:

1. the commit goes through and files are transferred but it never tells me and never finishes
2. I then have to control + c to get out of it because it's hug up
3. I have to svn cleanup because i control + c
4. then i have to svn up

can anyone help me figure out how to get my SVN back to normal?

Comment: Have you any post-commit hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. It turns out that the SVN database itself was corrupt and needed to be cleaned up.